# Allow rotation/landscape in one fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

My app has a single Activity with a FragmentPagerAdapter with four fragments (Using the ViewPagerIndicator library). One of these fragments has designs for both a separate portrait and landscape layout, the other three do not and need to be fixed to portrait orientation.

My thought was to set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest and call `getActivity().setRequestedScreenOrientation()` in the `onResume()` of all the fragments, locking to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` in three of them but to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` in the one that needs to allow rotation, but this doesn't work. The app remains in portrait mode.

Is there a way to achieve this?

It isn't actually necessary for the actual activity to rotate if there is anyway to allow a fragment to change orientation without its activity doing so, but I have not found anything mentioning this being possible. It would also be equally ok if the activity rotates since the tab bar will be hidden when in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Override `setUserVisibleHint()` in each fragment.

In the portrait only fragments:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

in the the portrait/landscape fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
}
```

This will allow the whole activity to rotate in one fragment, but fix it to portrait in others.

Comment: I wouldnt override the `setMenuVisibility` override `setUserVisible` they are both set at the same time, so both should act the same, just reads better using `UserVisible`

Answer (score 9):

One thing that worked for me was to just put

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

At the top of the `OnCreateView()` methods for each of the fragments. 
You would want to replace `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` with the appropriate `SCREEN_ORIENTATION` constant.

Once I did this it worked perfectly on ICS. You don't event have to adjust the manifest for the specific activity.

Comment: This sets it for the whole activity, not only the single fragment

Answer (score 4):

Issue is if you enable `configChanges` you then need to handle `onConfigurationChanged()` method in your activity/fragments.

Meaning that if you did fire the `getActivity().setRequestedScreenOrientation()` you would have to manually call `setContentView()` again to reinflate the landscape layout.

Also setting `UNSPECIFIED' will not change to landscape, it will just remain where it is.

I would use `getActivity().setRequestedScreenOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` for the portrait fragments.
And `getActivity().setRequestedScreenOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` for the landscape fragments.

This will reinflate the activity layout, which means you will then need to keep track of the last ViewPager page you where on, to make sure you show that after the layout has been recreated as to default back to that fragment before they are shown to the user and fragment `onResume()` is called.

Its going to be fiddly but, it is possible.

Comment: thanks for correcting me on the misuse of configChanges, and SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED

Answer (score 1):

Write some code in `AndroidManifest.xml` on the particular activity tag.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".
```

And Write code in Fragment on `onCreateView` method,
for Portrait:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
setRetainInstance(true);
```

for Landscape:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Comment: after change orientation fragment if i comeback to base fragment of activivty it remain landscape how to set it

Answer (score 0):

in the fragment you want to set just add to your `onCreate`/`onCreateView`

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in the other fragments you want to allow multi orientation add

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it to landscape for specific fragment, consider this. Remember to change it back to stopsActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT on fragment's lifecycle stop

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the the portrait/landscape fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
```

and you can change it to "ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT" or  "ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE"