# How to lock activity orientation without locking fragment orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

everyone! My question is inverted version of  [How to lock fragment orientation without locking activity orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370636/how-to-lock-fragment-orientation-without-locking-activity-orientation) , but nothing from there have worked for me.

The point is, that I have a camera app, where camera preview lays in activity, and an overlay with settings and other stuff - in fragment, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout    
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlayContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, I want to lock **camera preview orientation**, while keeping overlay orientation unlocked (as in camera apps in samsung, or sony smartphones).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try there  inside your fragment getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //For Portrait 
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//For Landscape

Comment: @RakshitNawani it also locks fragment orientation :(

Comment: So DON'T GIVE ORIENTATION TO YOUR ACTIVITY AND GIVE ORIENTATION TO THE FRAGMENTS

Comment: @RakshitNawani hm, but my question is exactly about your comment - how to give orientation exactly to fragment, not the activity.

Comment: You can add any of the below line according to your need to change orientation inside your onCreateView of your Fragment . getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //For Portrait getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)‌​;//For Landscape It will change the orientation of the fragment accordingly . Try it once

Comment: @RakshitNawani feeling myself stupid already. your code put BOTH fragment and activity in selected orientation, so, rotating device dont't change fragment orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle configuration change [by yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in a manifest.

So you have to override [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)).

Comment: Yep, and I've already override it, so activity is not recreate itself, but it still automatically rotates (the question is, how to prevent it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251930/allow-rotation-landscape-in-one-fragment

Answer (score 0):

In you manifest file

in any activity you want to set orientation of :) 
find this code and name of your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

then add the attribute to this android:screenOrientation=""

So that you can get required orientation of any activity :) by default

Comment: yep, but it locks fragment orientation too :(