# Android how to detect device rotation for portrait configured activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-manifest

I am developing a single activity application. It means I have a host activity and several different fragments. In the manifest, there is an attribute for activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" to suppress screen rotation. But in one of my fragments, I need to handle the device rotation to enable landscape orientation. Is there any way to handle the configuration change with attribute screenOrientation="portrait" for a specific fragment?

Comment: for the fragment, there is no config like Activity in XML as you asked. But you can set orientation using code for single fragment see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251930/allow-rotation-landscape-in-one-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant solution for such case.
In the specific fragment just set required orientation.

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        requireActivity().requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
```